# Select 3 fields from 10 fields in table with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities, compiler-errors

my query :

```
public List<Book> GetAllBook()
{
    return (from c in this.LDEntities.Book
             select new
             {
                 c.IdBook,
                 c.NameBook,
                 c.Athour
             }).ToList();
}
```

error :

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List

What is the correct code?

Update: I use from [Entity Framework in Layered Architectures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700340.aspx).

Comment: what does LDEntities.Book look like?  Linking to the article you're basing your application off of doesn't give us details of your classes.

Comment: Details of my class is like DataPoints2008_07...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
public List<Book> GetAllBook() {     

    var q = (from c in this.LDEntities.Book              
             select new Book() 
             { 
                 IdBook = c.IdBook, 
                 NameBook = c.NameBook, 
                 Athour = c.Athour }).ToList();     
    return (q); 
}
```

In other words, create a collection of type Book, not a collection of anonymous types.

Comment: I think you need `IdBook = c.IdBook` here.

Comment: Error : The entity or complex type 'LDModel.Book' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: This works but it bothers me that I have a Book object that is not completely hydrated.  As the calling code may or may not be aware of this situation.  I tend to create custom cut-down classes for this, I know its not ideal but I don't know if there is a better way.

Comment: @mrjac: Up to you to get your (Anonymous) Entities and DTOs straight. This is the best anybody can do with the details supplied.

Answer (score 3):

You are not converting to a `Book` instance. You would need to do something like this:

```
from c in LDEntities.Book
select new Book { /* Your Properties to Set */ }
```

What you're attempting to do is return an anonymous object as the return type. So it's trying to convert `List<a'>` to `List<Book>` and there is no relation between the two.

If you want only the anonymous object returned, you need to abstract the logic and make the method generic:

```
public List<T> GetAllBook<T>(Func<Book, T> transformer)
{
     return LDEntities.Book.Select(transformer).ToList();
}
```

And then you could call the code like so:

```
var myObjects = GetAllBook(x => new { c.IdBook, c.NameBook, c.Athour });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it'S

```
public List<Book> GetAllBook()
{
    var q = (from c in this.LDEntities.Book
             select c).ToList();
    return (q);
}
```

if LDEntities.Book are Book-objects